# Mongo connect failing

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp, pecl

I'm running mongodb on my local mac which was running fine in combination with MAMP. However it's not working, and when I call it in terminal, I now get this:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
connecting to: test
2017-02-23T18:43:39.841+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2017-02-23T18:43:39.842+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongo is off, you can run `mongod` to see where the initialization fails